# Angular 2 + Firebase Push Function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I currently have completed a tutorial which reads/writes to a Firebase using Angular2.

Need some help with the below function within the firebase.service.ts

```
addListing(listing){

  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  for (let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
  let path = `/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
  let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
  iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {

  listing.image = selectedFile.name;
  listing.path = path;
  return this.listings.push(listing);

  });

 }
 }
```

**Code that runs the function**

*Within the add-listing.component.html file*

```
<form (submit)="onAddSubmit()">
```

*Within the add-listing.component.ts file*

```
onAddSubmit(){
let listing = {

title:this.title,
city:this.city,
owner:this.owner,
bedrooms:this.bedrooms,
price:this.price,
type:this.type


}

this.firebaseService.addListing(listing);

this.router.navigate(['listings']);


}
```

This all works correctly - however I want to change the function to allow data to be pushed to the database without having to upload a image or file - currently the function wont run unless a image is included in the form.

Thanks for all your help.